# distinguish each label in a plot with 100 labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to plot 1100 points with 100 different labels. My problem is that with so many labels, it is not possible to distinguish each label from the other. Right now there is a minimal change in color for each label.

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
    sns.scatterplot(
    x="x", y="y",
    hue="label",
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 100),
    data=df_tsne,
    legend="full",
    alpha=0.3)
```

How can I set a different marker / color for every label to distinguish the points more easily?

Comment: Have you seen a readable plot with 100 labels, like *ever*?

Comment: This way it's possible to see the clusters that each labels form from the tSNE

Comment: Perhaps it would help to link a published example of what you are after.  Also define `tSNE`...

Comment: Something like this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328203076/figure/fig10/AS:731588820217899@1551435775877/T-SNE-visualization-of-all-FACS-cells-by-cluster-ID-n44-949-individual-cells-Clusters.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `ncols` argument for your legend.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "label": np.arange(1,101),
    "x": np.random.randint(0,100,100),
    "y": np.random.randint(0,100,100),    
})

plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="label", palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 100), data=df, legend="full", alpha=0.3)


plt.legend(ncol=4, loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))
```

Obviously, you can then adjust the location of the legend with `bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1)`.

[image]

If you wanted to also annotate the groups, which is not clear from your description, you could use the following code ([credit](https://nikkimarinsek.com/blog/7-ways-to-label-a-cluster-plot-python) to Nikki Marinsek), not for hundreds but just for 10:

```py
#create a new figure
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

customPalette = sns.color_palette("hls", 10)

#loop through labels and plot each cluster
for i, label in enumerate(data.label.unique()):

    #add data points 
    plt.scatter(x=data.loc[data['label']==label, 'x'], 
                y=data.loc[data['label']==label,'y'], 
                color=customPalette[i], 
                alpha=0.4, label=label)
    
    #add label
    plt.annotate(label, 
                 data.loc[data['label']==label,['x','y']].mean(),
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 size=20, weight='bold',
                 color='k'
                ) 
    
plt.legend(ncol=2)
```

Notice, that you have to find the centre of the patch (here it's its mean) and then go over all groups and annotate each of them.

The plot looks like this:
[image]